# Shell file to import SQLITE into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, shell

Ok, let me start off by saying that I'm don't have the slightest clue how to start off with this. I have an sqlite database. For simplicity lets just say that the table that I want to read is 'data' and data contains two fields, say (id, name). How could I go about creating a shell script to read the information from the 'data' sqlite table and insert it into a MYSQL table with the exact same table structure? I realise that it would be simpler to just insert the data into MYSQL to begin with and cut out the sqlite step all together, but this is not possible (unfortunately). I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20121018070614/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/941/4725.aspx

[corrected dead link. there is a C# script which accomplishes the objective]

Comment: I believe that will be more than sufficient. Of course I ended up finding this link on this site as soon as I get a reply to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/sqlite-export All well.

Comment: -1, no description and just a dead link.  Always leave a note.