# large amount of data insert into table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've to transfer the data from datatable to database. The total record is around 15k per time.
I want to redue the time for data inserting. Should I use ***SqlBulk***? or anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `C#` take a look on [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class. There is a [good article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net) on CodeProject about how to use it with `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

If you just aim for speed, then bulk copy might suite you well. Depending on the requirements you can also reduce logging level.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/edf280b9-2b27-48bb-a2ff-cab4b563dcb8/

[How to copy a huge table data into another table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296106/copying-a-huge-table-data-into-another-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: I just concern on about speed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL bulk copy is definitively fastest with this kind of sample size as it streams the data rather than actually using regular sql commands. This gives it a slightly longer startup time but with more than ~120 rows at a time (according to my tests)

Check out my post here on how to get here if you want some stats on how sql bulk copy stacks up against a few other methods.

http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/8/17/mssql_and_large_insert_statements

[image]

Answer (score 0):

15k records is not that much really. I have a laptop with i5 CPU and 4GB ram and it inserts 15k records in several seconds. I wouldn't really bother spending too much time on finding an ideal solution.