# How to tansfer sqlite local DB to the MySQL DB using web service with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, sqlite

I want to write web service which gets sqlite database from client device (i-phone app) and sync with server mysql DB. both sqlite and mysql has same DB table structure.

Should i accept json string from client for each table and parse it on the server end and get store the data in mysql DB. is it the right solution or is there any other solution for syncing both client and server DB ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has an option to dump the DB into a text file containing SQL commands. See [Exporting from SQLite to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/exporting-from-sqlite-to-sql-server) and http://sqlite.org/sqlite.html.

You can dump the SQLite into a file, have your program tweak the SQL a bit (remove table creation, triggers and other irrelevant stuff) and run it on the MySQL DB.

Comment: Do you have a clue how to write web service for it in PHP ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but working with SQLite looks the same - http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php