# Managing sql server database from sql lite or vice versa

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, jdbc

I'm a newbie,Can you please specify any tools or methods for managing sql server database from sqlite or vice versa...or both,if possible..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by managing? Neither MS SQL Server nor SQLite is a manager for SQL databases and specially not managers for each others.

For managing a SQL Server database, you can use `SQL Server Management Studio`.

For managing a SQLite database, you can use for example [Firefox SQLite manager plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

See also [how to export from SQLite to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/exporting-from-sqlite-to-sql-server?rq=1)