# importing csv to sqlite(firefox add-on) +TypeError: gFile.contents is null

Tags: sqlite, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv file into sqlite database (firefox add-on).

It has approximately 26,000 rows with 4 columns. Each time it gives this error:

> CSV Worker error! TypeError: gFile.contents is null File name: chrome://sqlitemanager/content/workerCsv.js Line number: 52

I already tried by splitting the csv file as well.

[image]

Comment: The strange thing is that the erro referer to a file in "chrome"? Do you have that .js File?

Comment: I don't have chrome installed

Comment: I just found that directory.its added with firefox extension folder without workerCsv.js file. I tried to add one by from internet but did not work :(

Comment: I am facing same problem. did you find any kind of solution.

Comment: I think that SQLite Manager is not fully compatible with Firefox 35.

Comment: why can't I add a bounty on this?

Comment: Is everyone getting this error? It is not related to file size. I think downgrading to firefox 34 is unreasonable

Comment: I used db browser for SQLite as it seemed that add-on is not compatible with firefox 35!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new Firefox 35 version corrected the bug [716491](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716491), which lead to this problem with the sqlite-manager addon. There seem to be two places in the addon, where some response code is tested. A solution is to replace these two lines. The addon path `chrome://sqlitemanager/content/workerCsv.js` is refering to one of this files. As a user of the addon, you can fix that in your version of the plugin as follows:

1. Go to your Firefox profile folder and the subfolder `extensions`
2. Rename the file `SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com.xpi` into `SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com.zip`
3. Extract the content of this zip file into a subfolder `SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com` within the `extension` folder and delete the zip file
4. Open the file `./SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com/chrome/content/workerCsv.js` with a reasonable text editor
5. Replace `if(req.status == 0) {` with  `if(req.status == 0 || req.status == 200) {` on line 20
6. Save it
7. Do the same with testCsv.js on line 15
8. Restart Firefox

This worked for me. I guess there are different ways to create the addon manually again. However, I hope this will be fixed in the official version.

Comment: Accept this answer. BTW profile folder on mac is located at: *~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>*

Comment: I followed these directions exactly on my Mac, and the SQLite Manager no longer shows under the Tools menu.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading to Firefox 34 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily db browser for SQLite saved me.seems like that add-
on is not compatible with firefox 35.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer won't tell you how to fix the problem *directly*... but, since I wasn't keen on downgrading Firefox, I looked around and I discovered [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/), a very good alternative to SQLite Manager, with many useful features and a pretty interface. Needless to say, it supports CSV import. It is cross-platform and FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to import simple CSV file, but it failed reporting exactly the same error. Downgrading from v35 to v.34.0.5(latest 34) fixed the issue on my Mac, running OSX 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

The new Firefox 35 version corrected the bug 716491, which lead to this problem with the sqlite-manager addon. There seem to be two places in the addon, where some response code is tested. A solution is to replace these two lines. The addon path chrome://sqlitemanager/content/workerCsv.js is refering to one of this files. As a user of the addon, you can fix that in your version of the plugin as follows:

Go to your Firefox profile folder and the subfolder extensions

On Windows 2000 and Windows XP, profile folders are in this location, by default:

**C:\Documents and Settings\ Windows login\user name\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ profile folder**

Rename the file SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com.xpi into SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com.zip

Extract the content of this zip file into a subfolder SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com within the extension folder and delete the zip file (you can omit this step)
Open the file **./SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com/chrome/content/workerCsv.js** with a reasonable text editor for instance notepad++

Replace **if(req.status == 0) {**

with

**if(req.status == 0 || req.status == 200) {**

on line 20

Save it!

Do the same with **testCsv.js** on line 15

Restart Firefox

if you want you can't delete the zip file, and copy **testCsv.js** and w**orkerCsv.js** and replace into zip file in **/chrome/content/**
after copy, just delete **SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com** the folder extracted from **SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com.zip**

Rename now zip file to xpi

That's it!

for other versions of windows look at **http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox** to find your profile path

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when going from Firefox 34 to 35. Firefox 36.0 fixed the problem however, so just upgrade to that new version.